# What does the whitelisting of starting a background Service from notification actions really mean for developers?

Tags: android, service, background, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

From the 2018 Google IO session [Migrate your existing app to target Android Oreo and above](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YyDnYaFtRS0&feature=youtu.be), they mention that there is an exception for not being able to start services in the background when it comes to a response from notification actions. What exactly does this exception mean?

We are currently using a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` to receive the action, which then generally starts a `Service` to run a network request and take action on result. I want to make sure that we are making the proper changes necessary (likely, using a foreground `Service`, if it is necessary. That being said, I don't want to make changes if they are not needed.

Does anyone know what the exception to not being able to start services while in the background actually means here and if there are any exceptions that may break this model (being in battery saver mode, for instance)?

In my testing on a Pixel 2 running Android P I have had no issues with this, but I want to make sure my users will not either.

Comment: Can you point to the specific time in the video in which you are talking about?

Comment: Good question! See 11:23

Comment: I don't see them say anything about there being an exception about not being able to start a service, all they say is there are cases that still allow you to start a service while in the background.

Comment: That is the exception since, normally, if you are targeting Android 26+ you cannot start services while in the background, right? I want to validate that there shouldn't be any issues (like the service being killed quickly after being started) with starting a service in response to a notification action in the way mentioned in the question.

Comment: The only thing different from the changes imposed in API 27 are the wake locks and the user can restrict background usage of apps. https://developer.android.com/preview/features/power#bg-restrict

Comment: Awesome, so it sounds like for this use case where we use a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` (which is now deprecated) to start a service which shouldn't be sucking up resources since it just runs a single network request that we should be golden to leave things as-is with the Android 26/27 changes?

Comment: One final question -- is the `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` even needed anymore? According to this, it seems like it is not since we should be able to start services from notification actions.